# Vicidial direct call in my web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to implement direct call feature via vicidial in my web application.

Let me explain the flow to better understand what I need to do. user would be able to login in vicidial via a webpage of my app. then can call on any number by entering number.

Is there any doc or wiki available to implement this feature. Guidance in simple steps would also be appreciating.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

We implemented something like that using a product called WombatDialer that offers good APIs and is quite easy to set up (well, easier than ViciDial).

See http://www.wombatdialer.com/manuals/WD_UserManual-chunked/ar01s08.html for an API reference.